# Loading time to read and display Data Extension rows with JS in CloudPages

Tags: ssjs, cloudpage, marketingcloudapi

I am trying to retrieve around 40,000 rows from my Data Extension into a CloudPage for an external 3rd party to consume this data.

The loading time of my cloudpage exceeds 2min, and it makes a timeout.

I would like to know if there is a function in SJSS to index the lines of my dataextension, like that, with each refresh, it recovers and treats just the new lines of my dataextension.

Any suggestions what the best method here would be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the third party software or product have the possibility to use the rest or soap api of salesforce? Then i would definitely go for this approach. Otherwise... how fast do you need the data - if its realtime use the apis. If you just need to import once a day or something like that, you can also cover it with automations and file exports to ftps.

Comment: It depends on your use case and how much data you want to receive. If you request millions of records and only have 2minutes of it, you will most likely fail with every api. So we would like to know more about the use case and the amount of data you need to grab.

Answer (score 2):

This would definitely be better done having the third party access the API directly, and not via a cloud page.  Adding in the CloudPage just brings in overhead that isn't necessary.  Depending on the fields you have available in the DE, they could then query on something like a date/time added field to only get new items since they last checked.